# Get JSON data from php with $_GET request in android

Tags: php, android, json, get

Here is my PHP code:

```
  $query = $sdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM `t_comments` WHERE `a_link` = ?");
    $query->bindValue(1, $_GET["link"]);
    $query->execute();
```

and here is my JSON request in Android:

```
JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest("http://serverip/json/getcomments.php?link=" + index, "GET", params);
```

Actually, this code works if I remove link request in Activity.
Also, if I replace `$_GET` with `ID` in PHP, but `index` will change on each request so.

SOLVED:
i needed to use Params list to add GET parameter inside
simply with `params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("STRING NAME", SOMETHING TO STORE));`

Comment: [Are you making network requests on the main user interface?](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = $sdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM `t_comments` WHERE `a_link` = :link");
$query->bindValue(':link', $_GET["link"]);
$query->execute();
```

Comment: it still does not works, plus this method used above proved that works (i`v used in different conditions) but in this case idk, it`s just can`t get $_GET value or idk what`s happening

$query->bindValue(1, 15); <- this code will work but...

Answer (score 0):

[From the documentation:](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php)

```
<?php
/* Execute a prepared statement by binding PHP variables */
$calories = 150;
$colour = 'red';
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT name, colour, calories FROM fruit
    WHERE calories < :calories AND colour = :colour');
$sth->bindValue(':calories', $calories, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->bindValue(':colour', $colour, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->execute();
?>
```

In your code:

```
if(isset($_GET["link"])){
    $aVarName = $_GET["link"];
    $query->bindValue(1, $aVarName, PDO::PARAM_INT);
} else {
    // Some error or default value.
}
```

Comment: Problem is solved, anyway thanks for finding time to help me :)

Comment: If the question is answered, chlick the green symbol below the left of the question. This marks the question as answered, and make it so other people can read an answer that helped solve the issue

Comment: well problem wasn`t in PHP, my PHP code worked very well it was inside json parse so... and by the way i already edited and added SOLVED + SOLUTION in main question